# Updating source in PowerQuery: Azure Data Pull via ODBC

Tags: apache-spark-sql, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I added a source in `PowerQuery` via `ODBC` to `Azure`, pulling data in free form query. On top of that I designed few new columns & measures in `PowerBI` and created report.

All good until I want to add some more columns in the free form query. My issue is:
 1. If I proceed to edit the query via editing from inside `Advanced Editor`, it's going to take longer time & error prone as well; testing & retesting until the query is properly written.
 2. Delete the existing source, add new `Spark SQL` query and run it without hassle. But then, create all the existing measures & columns again in `PowerBI`.

I don't see any other way to edit the same existing source in a hassle free way and retain my measures & columns of `PowerBI` intact.

Any pointers will be helpful.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea; guess I haven't had considered the editing of `Source` of the query; screenshot attached.[image]